# Is it possible to add a button in the servicem8 UI that will launch a web app or opens a native IOS app whilst also sending a UUID

Tags: servicem8

I am developing an app that will use servicem8 as it's job management. I would like to be able to launch the app from the job card within servicem8. The app will be a wrapped web app at this stage.I would like to open the app and send the job uuid or job_number to it.
Any help direction on this would be great

Comment: I just wanted to add to this question, I had a look more in-depth at the ServiceM8 add on documentation and wanted to know if it was possible to load the web app into the ServiceM8 pop up and make that pop up full screen theoretically using the pop up as a web wrapper. If so is there limitations to this and how would it be achieved

Comment: You can load your web app into the ServiceM8 popup, but you can't make it full screen -- your addon is rendered inside an iframe in ServiceM8, and the contents of that iframe cannot interact with the parent window (except for closing the popup and a couple other utility methods described in the docs)

Comment: Is there a way to have the button launch safari along with my URL and the job number as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example SDK addon, this launches an app from the job card within ServiceM8 (both online and within the iOS app)

https://github.com/servicem8/addon-sdk-samples/tree/master/hello-world-addon-nodejs

You could extend this example to have a full web app within the launched modal window.

Comment: so I have created the add on in developer and I have tried a tonne of different variations using iframe and window.location. There is no issue getting the page to load however I cannot get it to scroll. The web app scrolls fine when loaded outside of servicem8. Also it loads in safari which is not ideal, can i invoke launching a native app via the SDK once I wrap it and go native.

Comment: I have tried to add the code but it seams as if it too long